# React Native reusable data layer

Tags: react-native, mobile-development

As someone who comes from Angular I'm having a hard time grasping how to setup the concept of factories/services (data layer) in React Native(RN). How do I make a service/factory which can be reused in different views(components?) in RN?

Comment: Are you talking about Android services? I never used Angular. But, I'm using react for a long time. I never heard about concepts like factories/Services in React.

Comment: Angular has factories/services which can be reused in controllers, I'm wondering if react native has something similar...

Comment: You can take a look at the concepts Flux and Redux. Flux for instance has datastores and a concept of integrating these with your components.

Comment: React (and React Native) don't define anything but Components and their lifecycle. You are free to use whatever patter you like. The _suggested_ way to go about this is Flux. There are a lot of other ways too.

Comment: Check `React Elements`. That might be helpful for you. But, I'm not sure.